# JS how to use 'this' to point to its parent

Tags: javascript

```
var data = {
  data2 : {
    createNew : function() {
      data.data2 = 10; 
      // smth like `this = 10`
    }
  }
}
```

How can I use `this` to point to the `data.data2`, as I don't want to repeat `data.data2`?

Comment: Your JS code is not valid. Check the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Understand through the comments your question is actually, to access the `parent` from within `data2` .

You would need a constructor function (`root` is available in `data2` due to closures in javascript)

```js
function Data(){
    var root = this;
    this.data2  = {
        createNew : function() {
            data.data2 = 10;
            root.x = 10;

        }
    }
}

var data = new Data();
data.data2.createNew();
console.log(data.x);
```